# Why does Google Drive create so many conflicted files?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, google-apps

I have a Windows system and a Mac.
When I create a file (e.g. `a.cpp`) in Windows (with vim), Google Drive creates a lots of files like `a (1).cpp`, `a (2).cpp` ...
Some of them are delete by Google Drive after it creates them. Some are not.

Why does Google Drive generate so many files?

Also `a.cpp` is not the same as `a.cpp` in Windows. `a (2).cpp` in Mac is the same as `a.cpp` in Windows in some cases.

Why do the same files have different content?

When I check the access right of files, it should be something like

```
-rw------  ..................  a.cpp
```

However, when I create a file `b.cpp` in Mac it is

```
-rw-r--r-  ..................  b.cpp
```

Is it because of the accessing privilege problem?

Comment: Are you using google drive to control your code versions? Why don't you use a real version control, like git? I don't think that google drive is prepared to handle version control in a file that it's edited a dozen of times. Every time that you save your file, google drives understands it as a new version, and it probably causes your problem.

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/72655/274411

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the same issue, the problem it seems is when you 'edit' a file it get locked by the application and the google drive auto sync kicks in and creates a conflict file.

I notice this mostly with Photoshop files, as the files can get pretty large and the sync doesn't happen quickly like a simple text file and it cause a lot of duplicates.

**My solution:  pause google drive while I am working on these files and when done, let them sync.**